# How to remove end of string (fileName) using substring?

Tags: c#, wpf, substring, openfiledialog

I know I must use Substring to remove, but I dont know how to do this. I need to remove end of string like this

from

```
"C:\\Users\\myname\\Pictures\\shoeImage.jpg"
```

to

```
"C:\\Users\\myname\\Pictures"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `FileInfo` in such scenarios -

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo("C:\\Users\\myname\\Pictures\\shoeImage.jpg");
string name = info.DirectoryName;
```

OR

```
Path.GetDirectoryName("C:\\Users\\myname\\Pictures\\shoeImage.jpg");
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the methods of the `System.IO.Path` class instead, in specific [`GetDirectoryName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Path.GetDirectoryName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) method.

> Returns the directory information for the specified path string.

```
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName("C:\\Users\\myname\\Pictures\\shoeImage.jpg"));
```

It returns this;

```
C:\Users\myname\Pictures
```

Here a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/DQZYOC).

With [`String.SubString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) method, you can use it like;

```
string path = "C:\\Users\\myname\\Pictures\\shoeImage.jpg";
Console.WriteLine(path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf(@"\")));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to substring it:

```
var subString = yourString.SubString(0, yourString.LastIndexOf('\\'));
```

Comment: This won't even compile. You must use `('\\')` or `(@'\')`

Comment: Thanks. Forgot to escape it. Updated.