# Removing Letters from the end of a string

Tags: c#, string

I can not figure out how to remove the end of a string so I would have this.

```
string CurrentJob = @"F:\Jobs\Person\Selected Job\File" 
string BackCurrentJob = @"F:\Jobs\Person\Selected Job"
```

I want to be able to have the program look for the last instance that "\" Char appears and then remove everything after that.

**Answered**

I wanna thank everyone who commented I ended up going a different route then i planed to at first and used.

```
var x = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(CurrentJob);
```

Comment: lastindexof although I'm sure this is a duplicate

Comment: Look at [string.LastIndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof(v=vs.110).aspx) and [string.Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `string BackCurrentJob = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(CurrentJob)`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, good point that it's better to use the `Path` class when the string in question is a path.

Comment: As these are file paths, there are file path operations that would be clearer on what you are trying to do (vs. just string manipulation).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove end of string (fileName) using substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393409/how-to-remove-end-of-string-filename-using-substring)

Comment: this question just generally shows a lack of understanding of the problem and fundamentally laziness; a two minute google session would have provided 100's of solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LastIndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof(v=vs.110).aspx) is another option:

```
var x = CurrentJob.Substring(0, CurrentJob.LastIndexOf("\\"));
```

but for sure cleaner will be [GetDirectoryName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var x = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(CurrentJob);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help It was just one those days and google was not giving me the answers i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Since your input string is a filesystem path, use the [`System.IO.Path` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using System.IO;
// ...
string CurrentJob = @"F:\Jobs\Person\Selected Job\File"; 
string BackCurrentJob = Path.GetDirectoryName(CurrentJob);
```

---

The [`GetDirectoryName()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx) will return the parent directory path *without* a trailing `/`, so if you need to subsequently combine it with another relative path, use [`Path.Combine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) (rather than fiddling around with optional `/`'s):

```
string CurrentJobLog = Path.Combine(BackCurrentJob,@"job.log");
```

Comment: Thank you for your help this was what i was looking for  I am still learning. C# and most the stuff i figure out on my own but for the life of me i just could not figure this one out.

Answer (score -1):

```
string BackCurrentJob = Path.GetDirectoryName(CurrentJob);
```

This returns the output of: `F:\Jobs\Person\Selected Job`

The Below link explains everything  needed to know about the Path.GetDirectoryName method:

[Path.GetDirectoryName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)